# Clojure / lein repl & Metadata - is this a bug, and where?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I use the Leiningen 2 REPL with Clojure 1.3.
I get an inconsistent behavior (or so I think) with meta data.

If this is as it should be, please explain. If not - where shall I file the bug?

This is how metadate should work, AFAIK.

```
main=> (def a ^:inited  [ 1 2 3])
main=> (meta a)
{:inited true}
```

And this is what I get when refering to an quoted empty sequence.

```
main=> (def a ^:inited  '() )
main=> (meta a)
nil

main=> (def a ^{:inited (System/currentTimeMillis)} '())
main=> (meta a)
nil
```

For an unquoted empty sequence, everything is fine. But, well, I get line numbers.

```
main=> (def a ^{:inited (System/currentTimeMillis)} ())
main=> (meta a)
{:inited 1339678437612, :line 1}

main=> (def a ^:inited  () )
main=> (meta a)
{:inited true, :line 1}
```

Here I don't get line numbers:

```
main=> (def a ^:inited  [ 1 2 3])
main=> (meta a)
{:inited true}

main=> (def a ^{:inited (System/currentTimeMillis)} [1 2 3])
main=> (meta a)
{:inited 1339678534644}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'` is a reader macro which expands to `(quote ...)`. So you put the meta data on the list. Try this:

```
user=> (def a ' ^:inited [])
#'user/a
user=> (meta a)
{:tag :inited}
user=> (def a ^:inited '[])
#'user/a
user=> (meta a)
nil
```

[Shameless self-promotion.](http://kotka.de/blog/2009/12/with-meta_and_the_reader.html)

Comment: Haha. Yes. Of course. Should have seen that. (Any hints on the line number thing?)

Comment: They are added by the compiler for error reporting. lists are used for function calls.